# Install Eigen3 for Xcode5

Tags: c++, xcode5, eigen3

I hope I dont get downvoted, but I have search online and the Eigen wiki and I cant find instructions on how to install Eigen3 to use it on Xcode5.

I downloaded the tar file and untar it, but then I dont know where to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it.

Because in Eigen3 there is no library to link to. What you have to do is to untar the downloaded file and then copy the `Eigen` folder into

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
```

After that you can create any project and just add the headers of Eigen3

To try it, you can run a the following example given in the "Getting started" guide:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

That has the following output:

```
  3  -1
2.5 1.5
```